# Keep button pressed in IOS when App reopens

Tags: ios

I am making an Iphone app and I have a user click a button and it changes the sorting in my fetched results controller. However after I close my app it changes back to the original way it was sorted. i was just wondering if there is anyway to keep that button pressed when the app reopens.

```
- (IBAction)btnValue:(id)sender {
self.model.frc_Work.delegate = self;

 NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Value" ascending:YES];
self.model.frc_Work.fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Just use `NSUserDefaults` to store information:

```
// Set this to the correct value when the button is pressed
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"ButtonPressedKey"];
```

then, when you're laying out your button:

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"ButtonPressedKey"]){
    // Do whatever you're currently doing to keep the button pressed during runtime.
}
```

`NSUserDefaults` is basically an `NSDictionary` that persists across app launches. It only stores property-list values (`NSNumber, NSString, NSData, NSArray, NSDictionary, and NSDate`) and primitives like `BOOL`s.

Here's an example project demonstrating this using a `UISwitch`: https://github.com/MaxGabriel/ButtonPersistence

Comment: so would I have it like this:

- (IBAction)btnValue:(id)sender {
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"ButtonPressedKey"]){
self.model.frc_Work.delegate = self;

 NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Value" ascending:YES];
self.model.frc_Work.fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];

And add the first part of the code in the viewDidLoad?

Comment: The other way around. The first part of the code goes in the `IBAction` method that happens when you press your button (it shouldn't always be `YES` -- if there are only two states for the button it should flip between them). The second part goes in `viewDidLoad`. What that code does is check NSUserDefaults for whatever the button state is that you saved in a previous run of the application, and then it sets it to the right state.

Comment: @Joe24 I added an example project to github that demonstrates how you would do it using a `UISwitch`.